# Is it possible a recursive compression algorithm based on L-systems or a variant?

Tags: ds.algorithms, computability

According to the Internet, [there's a way to get an L-system's rules by it's string](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/abstractMetrics.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5597971&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D5597971), unfortunately I can't read it because it's behind a paywall.

**Question:** If that paper is right, is it possible to make an algorithm, based on L-systems, to recursively reduce let's say a blob of 64MB of zeros and ones down to:

- A ***"small"* starting axiom**.
- A **set of variables/constants/you-name-it**.
- A **set of rules**.
- The **number n of iterations** required.

**/Question End**

Compression is all about entropy and something in my guts says this isn't possible, I'd like someone with more experience to confirm it.

Comment: Isn't this essentially how Lempel-Ziv-etc works?

Comment: @JɛﬀE Isn't LZ- just one pass?

Comment: _all_ grammars can double as [compression algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar-based_code). & $K(x)$ from kolmogorov complexity is the ultimate grammar compression.